# class pointer error: does not have a type

Tags: c++, class, pointers

one of my class variables that is a pointer to another class is giving a error of no type. can figure it out after a few days thinking about it, anyone see a mistake? also for some reason the line

```
 r->setright(NULL)
```

crashes the program

```
#include "gridnode.h"
#include "grid.h"
#include "basenode.h"
class grid
{
    public:
        grid();
        void print();
    protected:
        gridnode *head;//error of no type here
};
#endif // GRID_H
```

and my node class

```
class gridnode:public basenode
{
public:
    char mark;
    gridnode *l, *r, *u, *d;
    gridnode(){
        l->setleft(
        r->setright(NULL);//crashes
        u->setup(NULL);
        d->setdown(NULL);
    }
    //set and get functions
protected:
};
```

any help greatly apreciated.

Comment: Hi @jack3939. Currently, there is not enough information to answer this question. If this is crashing on `setright` then could you please share that Implementation?

Comment: this program is basically a 2d array implemented with linked lists. set right should just set the variable r to the node to the right of the current node, but it will not set the one to the right as NULL.currently setright and setdown cause the program to crash, but setup and setleft work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one of my class variables that is a pointer to another class is giving a error of no type.

`gridnode` has not been defined yet when you try to use it.  That can happen if you have circular references in your `.h` files, for instance.  Since you are just declaring a pointer, you can use a forward declaration instead:

```
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H

// there should be no include of grid.h here
// move the gridnode.h and basenode.h includes to grid.cpp instead

class gridnode; // forward declaration

class grid
{
    public:
        grid();
        void print();

    protected:
        gridnode *head;
};

#endif // GRID_H
```

> also for some reason the line
>
> ```
> r->setright(NULL)
> ```
>
> crashes the program

Inside the `gridnode` constructor, you are calling methods on `l`, `r`, `u`, and `d` pointers that have not been initialized to point at anything.  You are invoking undefined behavior by calling methods on them.  You probably meant to set the pointers themselves to `NULL` instead, eg:

```
gridnode(){
    l = NULL;
    r = NULL;
    u = NULL;
    d = NULL;
}
```

Or:

```
gridnode() :
    l(NULL),
    r(NULL),
    u(NULL),
    d(NULL)
{
}
```